# Save image in Windows Mobile 5.0 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am saving image in windows mobile application using C#.My code is

```
    SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        aspectRatioPictureBox1.Photo.Save(dialog.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
```

In the above code i am able to save only in folders of MyDocument But
i am not able to browse to save in other folders..

Please let know the code to save image through browsing the location

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: There is no exception...
I am not able to save to other folder through browsing..
It defaultly shows the folders of Mydocuments..

Answer (score 0):

The default open and save file dialogs are not very good at all.

Firstly they can only look at My Documents and sub folders. Secondly the user interface is very poor and old fashioned.

We ended up rolling our own file save dialog. And while we where at it we also added gesture based scrolling and file text which was large enough to use with a finger. I would definitely recommend finding an alternative or writing your own which is a good exercise in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The default Open and Save dialogs are just very limited, there's little you can do if you keep using them.

If you browse around though, I'm sure you can find alternative implementations for these dialogs. One of the first that came up in a quick google search is [this one](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=212). I haven't tested it and I'm sure there are others, but it may give you a start.